# Is there an R function like rstatx::wilcox_test() applicable to categorical variable?

Tags: r, statistics, hypothesis-test

My data look like this:

```
my_data <- tibble(animal = c(rep("cat", 5), rep("dog", 8), rep("cow", 10)), 
       age = c("old", "old", "young", "adult", "old", "old", "young", "adult", "old", "old", "young", "adult", "old", "young", "adult", "old", "old", "young", "adult", "old", "old", "young", "adult"))
```

If I want to compute Chi Squared test I make:

```
my_data_table <- table(my_data)
rstatx::chisq_test(my_data)
```

Now, what I want to do is to obtain a contingency table similar to the one I will obtain by applying `rstatx::wilcox_test()` function on numerical variable. Any suggestion about statistical test and function that I may use on my data table in order to obtain the contingency table I am trying to make?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you meant `library(dplyr);library(tidyr);my_data %>% count(across(everything())) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = age, values_from = n) %>% column_to_rownames('animal') %>% chisq_test`

Comment: I was wondering if there are statistical tests similar to wilcoxon that:
1) Are good for qualitative data;
2) gave as output a contingency table with all the differences between groups.